# Laravel redirect if authorization failed using gates

Tags: laravel, redirect, authorization, http-redirect

In my application I am using `gates` to validate the `authorization` of the logged in user. I want the user to be redirected to dashboard, with a custom message, instead of showing the traditional `403 | This action is unauthorized.` page.

Here is my code:

```php
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        # access
        if(!$this->authorize('some-role'))
        {
            session->set('message', 'message');

            return redirect()->route(...);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

***Is this possible..?***

Comment: You can use Reportable & Renderable Exceptions - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#renderable-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy way inside controller check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates):

```
if (Gate::denies('update-post', $post)) {
// The current user can't update the post...
}
```

Proper way.
There is `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` there is render method where you can set you [custom exception](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors) `NotAuthorizedException` (laravel < 5.5):

```
if($exception instanceof NotAuthorizedException){
        return redirect($exception->route());
    }
```

If laravel > 5.6 you can add below code and redirect inside `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` the `render` method:

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException)
```

Comment: Thanks @Arman. I am using Laravel 7.x. The condition worked for me. However, I tried the other codes but didn't work. Is it because I am using `Gates`.?